# Mandarin Equivalent of 啥子树子招啥虫?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests, equivalent-phrase, topolect

Heard `啥子树子招啥虫` used in the same sense as "不是一家人，不进一家门" - I was wondering if there is a similar phrased expression in Mandarin for the first, mentioned, expression.

Comment: Maybe like "物以类聚, 人以群分".

Comment: It is not the same.In Chinese,there are commendatory term and derogatory term.啥子树子招啥虫is used when you hate someone,and "不是一家人，不进一家门"is used when you appreciate someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 啥子树子招啥虫 emphasizes more on similarity of couples of marriage.

龙生龙，凤生凤，老鼠儿子会打洞。

Dragon's son must be a dragon, phoenix's son must be a phoenix, and that of a mouse must can dig holes.

Meaning:

A great man teaches out great sons, a noble man cultivates noble sons. Normal people have only normal posterities.

Sometimes we neglect the second half of the phrase, i.e. just 龙生龙，凤生凤.

Answer (score 0):

虎父无犬子 would also be a good one.（Literally means tiger fathers don't have dog sons）